# How to change subpixel layout from default RGB in Infinality?

Tags: fonts, subpixel-rendering

I have [Infinality](http://www.infinality.net/blog/infinality-freetype-patches/) patches installed, however fonts look not so good. Using [subpixel layout detection page at lagom.nl](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/subpixel.php) I discovered that my monitor has BGR layout, but Infinality uses default RGB.

How can I configure Infinality to use BGR subpixel font rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change setting called `rgba` from `rgb` to `bgr`.

```
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="rgba" mode="assign">
      <const>bgr</const> <!-- here -->
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

I'm on Arch, and for me it was in `/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail.infinality/10-base-rendering.conf`. On your system it might be different, just grep for `rgba` in all `*.conf` files. A reboot/X restart might also be required.

EDIT
I just realized that a package upgrade might revert this back to the default. So the *right* location for this is `etc/fonts/local.conf`, you can create it if it doesn't exist.